# Debugging a libgdx application from the terminal JDB

Tags: java, debugging, gradle, libgdx, jdb

I have been working on a LibGDX game/application, and due to the use of Gradle was not really sure how to debug it.

I don't use an IDE and mostly debug with **JDB** but couldn't find anywhere how to do it.

The [documentation](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/documentation/gettingstarted/Running%20and%20Debugging.html#command-line-running) is not very revealing either.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I have found is to run th program in debug mode with:

```sh
gradle desktop:debug
```

Gradle will then start listening to a socket and prompt it:

```sh
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
```

In a second terminal you need to launch `jdb` with the `-attach` flag followed by the socket:

```sh
jdb -attach 5005
```

From this point onward you can debug the program, as you would normally do with **jdb**.